# ubuntu plays mp3 files in a 'funny' sound

Tags: ubuntu, audio, mp3

I am running ubuntu 10.10. And I have installed
gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3
gstreamer0.10-ffmpg
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly

I can play mp3 files using rhythmbox.
I can hear the singer sings in the mp3 file, but it is not the real voice of the singer.
Is there anything I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a setup that is not average (e.g., not a simple, two-channel output setup)?  I have a 5.1 surround sound system on my computer (with support for that on-board the motherboard), and sometimes PulseAudio will forget how to play sound with it.  The solution that typically works for me is to go into the sound preferences screen (by clicking on the little "speaker" at the top-right of the display), go to the Hardware tab, and then change the audio profile from 5.1 to something else, and then back.

Even if you have only a two-channel or 2.1 channel setup, you might want to try that---while the audio is playing---to see if that will fix anything.

Comment: +1 for the speakers' setup: if your OS is trying to play the audio in a 5.1 setup, but you have a 2.1, chances are you miss the front or rear sounds. Try to change the software configuration to fit your hardware, e.g. your pc has only two speakers (left and right) go for 2.1 or built-in speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Not the real voice? Does it sound electronic or something? Try playing the file with vlc media player. Might make a difference. If not then go under snyaptic and search for gstreamer. If you see a program that has gstreamer in the name and has something to do with mp3s but is uninstalled you could try it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug remotely with little information.

This could be that you don't have drivers for the hardware (used to be like this on macbooks, for example), that you have connected or configured the speakers wrong, or that you forgot to pull out the headphones from the headphone socket.

Just as some of many possible reasons.

Other than drivers it's unlikely to be a software problem, though.